# Include a CSS file

Tags: php, laravel

In ytform, my demo project for Laravel 4.2 fails when I attempt to add a CSS file (style.css) from the public folder that contains a separate CSS folder. It is not working to try to get any class.

```
in view of I'm trying to access this CSS file from another folder called layouts, but it's not working.
```

within the `master.blade.php` file

```
<head>
    @section('head')
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    @show
    
</head>
```

I tried the two methods provided, but to no avail. No view folder files support CSS files. Adding CSS Files

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

    {{HTML::style('css/style.css')}}
```

any error or solution?

Comment: post your file structure here

Comment: --->public-folder--->css-folder=style.css

Comment: --->publicfolder--->jsfolder=app.js file

Comment: --->Viewfolder--->layoutfolder=master.blade.php

Comment: i am including style.css file and app.js into head section of master.blade.php but not working ?

Comment: The reason we're asking where the files are is because you have both `/css/style.css` and `css/style.css` as sources ( `/css/` is root css as the server sees it, `css/` is relative to the file that's linking to it).  Try putting them in the same folder and use `style.css` instead of `css/style.css` or `/css/style.css` for troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks for reply Deryck, i past full path now it is working : src ="http://localhost/ytforum/public/css/style.css"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

You can try this

or

```
{{ HTML::style(asset('css/site.css'), array('rel' => 'stylesheet', 'type' => 'text/css')) }}
```

and the css files needs to be in the public folder for this to work

Comment: where are your css files? In which folder?

Comment: in public folder----->css folder , style.css is going in css folder

Answer (score 1):

Just include some lines in `Blade template`

```
{{ HTML::style('css/main.css') }}
```

See [here](http://www.tannerhearne.com/link-to-css-file-laravel-using-html-class/) as a reference

Comment: yes i added same , but not work css file : {{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}

Comment: Avinash Babu u have another solution ?